# Correct way to push in string[] react+typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

What is the correct way to push elements in string[] in react?
I'm getting  `Type '(string | string[])[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'`

This is a playground link : [Here](https://playcode.io/893658)

Am I not initializing the string correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing a square bracket in your example code:

```js
| null>(['')
```

Should be

```js
| null>([''])
```

Change line 8 so you're also spreading the second array, and it fixes your problem:

```js
setArr((prev: string[])=> [...prev, ...tempArr])
```

Comment: Yeah, but I still get the same error as described above